# How to echo this result in php 'mg/dl';

Tags: php, mysql, string, mysqli, echo

While printing or echo the result of 'mg/dl' is resulting

**Warning!: Comment is disabled for security reasons.**

EXAMPLE :

```
$fff = 'mg/dl';
echo $fff;
```

RESULT :
Warning!: **Comment is disabled for security reasons.**

EXPECTED RESULTS is

```
mg/dl
```

Comment: whic php version?

Comment: For me it's working fine, once check your PHP version

Comment: what if you escape the special character like - `$fff = 'mg\/dl';`

Comment: YES. @VESHRAJ JOSHI.. ACTUALLY my problem is that one only.. i'm just encodeing that to json. that time i have faced that issue.

Comment: I have solved it with $rr = '130mg/dl';
echo json_encode($rr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

Comment: Where does that error message come from?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. The problem i have faced is while doing `jsonencode();`

whatever result is coming with forward/backslash ( **'130mg/dl'** ) is resulting ( **'130mg/\dl'** )

Now it is OK. with **JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES**

```
$rr = '130mg/dl';
echo json_encode($rr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score -1):

That's what I did:

```
$fff = "'mg/dl'";
echo $fff;`
```